# Как в декораторе в Python определить счетчик другой функции?

Tags: python, вывод, декоратор

Реализую нахождение корней уравнения с одной переменной методом дихотомии. Там суть: отрезок несколько раз делится пополам. Если функция на середине отрезка составляет ноль либо меньше заданной погрешности - корень найден. Иначе деление продолжаем, и за границы отрезка принимается то левый, то правый его "рубежи".

Вывод результатов организовал в функции-обертке, чтобы данный функционал вывода не влиял на расчет времени исполнения главной задачи - поиска корней.

Требуется, кроме прочего, указать количество итераций (сколько раз делили отрезок пополам). Как сделал сейчас (и понимаю сам, что неверно), не получается. Ошибка:

> NameError: name 'counter' is not defined

Как быть? Код:

```
import numpy as np

def print_dichotomy(dichotomy):
    def wrapper(a,b,n, eps):
        print('Корни по методу дихотомии находятся в точках:')
        print(', '.join(map(lambda x: f'{x:.4f}', res)))
        print('Количество итераций: ', counter)   # ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА
    return wrapper

def f(x):
    return 1.2-np.log(x)-4*np.cos(2*x)

@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy (a,b,n, eps): # отрезок от a до b делим на n частей, погрешность eps
    """
    Функция отделения и уточнения корня
    """
    assert a!=0,  'a равно 0'
    assert b!=0, 'b равно 0'
    
    # сначала отделим корни
    grid=np.linspace(a, b, n)
    
    # далее уточним корни
    counter=0
    for x,y in zip(grid, grid[1:]):
        if f(x) * f(y) > 0: # если на отрезке нет корня, смотрим следующий
            continue
        root = None
        while ( abs(f(y)-f(x)) )>eps:     # пока отрезок больше заданной погрешности, выполняем нижестоящие операции:
            mid = (y+x)/2                   # получаем середину отрезка
            if f(mid) == 0 or f(mid)<eps:    # если функция в середине отрезка равну нулю или меньше погрешности:
                root = mid                  # корень равен серединному значению
                counter+=1
                break
            elif (f(mid) * f(x)) < 0:       # иначе если произведение функции в середине отрезка на функцию в т. а <0
                y = mid                     # серединой становится точка b
            else:
                x = mid                     #в другом случае - точка а
        if root:
            yield root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы получаете сообщение об ошибке, потому что counter является локальной переменной функции dichotomy. Она существует только внутри области видимости этой функции. Вне этой функции, данная переменная не видна.

И поскольку функция dichotomy не возвращает в результате своей работы наружу значение переменной counter никаким образом, то по завершении работы функции, переменная counter перестает существовать.

Следовательно, нужно переопределить counter таким образом, чтобы она находилась не в локальной, а в глобальной области видимости. Для этого можно использовать инструкцию global внутри функции dichotomy. Это не самое красивое решение, но оно позволит решить поставленную вами задачу. Таким образом, counter становится глобальной переменной, и мы инициализируем ее до вызова функции dichotomy. Теперь мы сможем использовать значение переменной counter после выполнения функции dichotomy.

Второй момент, на который хотел бы обратить внимание - я не увидел, чтобы внутри функции-обертки wrapper вы вызывали передаваемую в нее функцию. По этой причине возникает еще одна ошибка, что переменная res не определена. Вместо нее нужно как раз поместить вызов исходной функции, полученной в параметрах функции print_dichotomy.

В результате сказанного, код может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
import numpy as np


def print_dichotomy(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Корни по методу дихотомии находятся в точках:')
        print(', '.join(map(lambda x: f'{x:.4f}', func(*args, **kwargs))))
        print('Количество итераций: ', counter)

    return wrapper


def f(x):
    return 1.2 - np.log(x) - 4 * np.cos(2 * x)


@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy(a, b, n, eps):  # отрезок от a до b делим на n частей, погрешность eps
    """
    Функция отделения и уточнения корня
    """
    global counter
    assert a != 0, 'a равно 0'
    assert b != 0, 'b равно 0'

    # сначала отделим корни
    grid = np.linspace(a, b, n)

    # далее уточним корни
    for x, y in zip(grid, grid[1:]):
        if f(x) * f(y) > 0:  # если на отрезке нет корня, смотрим следующий
            continue
        root = None
        while (abs(f(y) - f(x))) > eps:  # пока отрезок больше заданной погрешности, выполняем нижестоящие операции:
            mid = (y + x) / 2  # получаем середину отрезка
            if f(mid) == 0 or f(mid) < eps:  # если функция в середине отрезка равну нулю или меньше погрешности:
                root = mid  # корень равен серединному значению
                counter += 1
                break
            elif (f(mid) * f(x)) < 0:  # иначе если произведение функции в середине отрезка на функцию в т. а <0
                y = mid  # серединой становится точка b
            else:
                x = mid  # в другом случае - точка а
        if root:
            yield root


counter = 0
dichotomy(1, 11, 15, 0.01)
```

Comment: благодарю за подробный ответ! При перенесении сюда кода действительно не указал строку `res = list(dichotomy(a,b,n, eps))` - с ней у меня работает обертка